# EF 5 - Sometimes returns dynamic proxy even though ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

Tags: entity-framework

I've been observing that sometimes my queries return proxies, and sometimes they don't, after I specify 
this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

I'm totally at a loss.  Does anybody know why this can sometimes happen?  Is it a bug?

I had code that did:

```
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        var result = query();
```

Where query was a "SingleOrDefault". This returned a poco just fine.

I then changed it to return a list by getting rid of "SingleOrDefault" and using a "Where" clause---and now it returns a list of proxies rather than the poco.

Answer (score 2):

I think I finally found the answer to this annoying problem.

[EF5 DBContext configuration ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14951826/ef5-dbcontext-configuration-ignored)

Basically, if the object is cached in the db context as a proxy, then it will be returned as a proxy regardless of whether or not the configuration says not to use proxies.

The solution would be to create a new context and then do the query, or turn proxy creation off always rather than dynamically changing the configuration at runtime.

Comment: How do you turn  proxy creation off ?

Comment: this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;  put that in your context's constructor.

Comment: good catch on a reused object context pulling it from the cache as dynamic.